# Changing branch from GitHub Desktop resets path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-desktop

Whenever I switch a branch using github desktop, it resets the path from # PATH=/Users/syedhamza/.rbenv/bin:/Users/syedhamza/.rbenv/shims:/Users/syedhamza/.rbenvgi

to # PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin

such that it changes the ruby version from 3.2.1 to the default 2.6.

Any idea why this happens?

I have to reset the path everytime by running the following commands:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```